# Getting "--> ;" on front page after editing custom html.tpl file

Tags: 7, theming

I am newbie and using Drupal - 7.

I have added script tags into my customized html.tpl file.

```
<script async src="http://i.simpli.fi/dpx.js?cid=0&segment=Segment+Name&campaign_id=0"></script>
```

And now I am getting this "**--> ;**" into front page of my website.

This is the code for my customized html.tpl. file with script tags.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.0//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-1.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php print $language->language; ?>" version="XHTML+RDFa 1.0" dir="<?php print $language->dir; ?>"<?php print $rdf_namespaces; ?>>
<head profile="<?php print $grddl_profile; ?>">
  <?php print $head; ?>
  <title><?php print $head_title; ?></title>
  <?php print $styles; ?>
 <!-- <?php print $scripts; ?> --> 
</head>
<body<?php print $attributes;?>>
<?php print $scripts; ?>
<script async src="http://i.simpli.fi/dpx.js?cid=0&segment=Segment+Name&campaign_id=0"></script> 
  <div id="skip-link">
    <a href="#main-content" class="element-invisible element-focusable"><?php print t('Skip to main content'); ?></a>
  </div>
  <?php print $page_top; ?>
  <?php print $page; ?>
  <?php print $page_bottom; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone please help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers. This is not a Drupal question, since you would get the same with plain PHP, or WordPress.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: This error occurs in template file due to php code. And html.tpl.php file is in Drupal and this type of question/answer is very helpful to newbie like me.

Comment: Yes, but the PHP in a template file is not different from the PHP you could write without using Drupal. PHP syntax doesn't change, and a PHP comment is not different, if you are using Drupal, WordPress, or plain PHP.

Comment: Yes this thing is right from experienced person but from newbie perspective, when you are new to drupal, sometimes you may not realize that this is just php code which gives an error. You always start thinking that may be something breaks in drupal code or may be I edited wrong file in drupal which gives an error.

Comment: The question doesn't require any Drupal knowledge; I just need to know PHP basics, to answer it. If a question doesn't require Drupal expertise to answer it, then it is not about Drupal, and it is off-topic here. It's not that, since you are using Drupal, then it is a Drupal question. It is a Drupal question if only the users who know Drupal can answer it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess your problem comes from this line :

```
   <!-- <?php print $scripts; ?> -->
```

Don't comment things this way. Rather do :

```
  <?php /* print $scripts; */ ?>
```

Or even better just **delete the line** if not needed.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, the commented out line could simply be removed, since there is another line outputting the same.

Answer (score 5):

it is probably stemming from this line:

```
<!-- <?php print $scripts; ?> -->
```

`<!-- -->` is a commenting system for HTML, but the item you are trying to comment out is php, which uses a different method for commenting.

you would use the html commenting around html elements:

```
<!-- <div>Hello World!</div> -->
```

whereas for php:

```
<?php //print $scripts; ?>
```

or

```
<?php /*print $scripts;*/ ?>
```

would be appropriate.

Comment: Thanks @rtome and @ Geoff. I have deleted that comment line and error "--> ;" goes away.
Thank you so much.